# How to increase current while keeping the voltage the same?

Tags: arduino, voltage, transistors, amperage

I currently have an Arduino Uno board which has an output of around 5V @ 900mA.

Is it possible to bump up the current to around 3-4A while keeping the voltage the same? Maybe with a transistor, but I am new to this and don't know if such a transistor exists.

Comment: Show schematic for your Uno regulator

Comment: do not use the Arduino as a power supply ... use an external power supply that is able to provide the required voltage and current

Comment: It would help us to know what load you want to drive with your 5 V and 4 A.

Answer (score 1):

How to increase current while keeping the voltage the same?

```
I = U / R
```

reduce the resistance!

But you're talking about Arduino outputs.

First: there is a confusion here regarding the power supply of the Arduino itself vs. the load that the pins can drive. What I do is I have my 5 V x 4 A power supply for my circuits, and I do not use the Arduino power supply from the USB plug for that. All you need to do is connect the Arduino ground (GND) pin to the ground of your external power rail. You do not connect the +5V pins with each other, not needed.

Now, to actually switch husky loads with your Arduino pins, you guessed right that you need transistors. Power transistors to be exact, or ideally a MOSFET or a relay. Even for a relay you might need a transistor to drive the current needed for the solenoid.

Using a classic bipolar junction transistor (NPN or PNP) is a problem because you still need current to drive current. So you run out of current from your pin. But there are ways around it, I'm showing below. First the MOSFET.

A MOSFET is a voltage controlled device that requires almost no gate current. You can try a 2N7000 if you're working on breadboards:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZiCkM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 2N7000 can switch 200 mA, the BS170 can do 500 mA. You need more? You can do some bigger MOSFET in a TO-220 package. I don't have a standard part number handy right now.

Here is the same with a BJ transistor, can use a BC546/7/8 here instead of 2N2222,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgWdvI.png)</sup>

but those are medium power, again, only in the few-hundred mA range. They don't get you to amperes ranges, so you can run them in a Darlington configuration:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4SX4c.png)</sup>

The TIP41 should do a few amps (with heat sink!); or, whatever bigger power transistor you want, maybe even those old fat 2N3055 power transistors with 15A collector current.

There are also Darlington pairs in a single package, like the popular TIP122, it feels as if you were connecting the TIP41 directly, just that there are two transistors inside in the Darlington configuration.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffpwa6.png)</sup>

You can replace the load with a relay and then you can drive 110/220 V circuits at whatever power you want. I think you might be able to drive a small suitable relay directly off the pin or you might need a little BC247/2N2222 instead as per the second schematic above.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a matter of adding more regulators matched to the same voltage to share the load.  The highest voltage regulator hogs more current so they just have to be matched within 1%. A trimpot with an adjustable regulator with fixed R limits to fine tune 5V to achieve thermally matched (shared current * Voltage drop) regulators is a good way to to it. Heatsink-wise is up to your mechanical and research skills.

A more efficient way is to gang an external 5V regulator and add reverse protection power diode (1N400x) between pins 2 & 3 on IC1 or IC2 below in case of power sequence differences.

They already have 2 in parallel on the Uno board.

[image]

[ref](http://circuitscheme.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/arduino-uno-schematic.jpg)

Comment: Like i said im very new to this.. so do you mean that adding voltage regulators increases the current? and if yes what voltage regulator do i need and how many to bring it to the desired Amperage? This circuit diagram is very confusing for me..

Comment: Use the same as on board or equivalent

Comment: i dont know which one that is on the board. it is an arduino uno...
but does that mean i only need the same voltage regulator and then i can draw more current while keeping the voltage the same?

Comment: If you cannot recognize the 2 regulators on the  right side of this schematic on the  board, I cannot help.

Comment: @JP2K, at your level of electronics knowledge you might get better help on [Arduino Stackexchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @ThePhoton - I doubt Arduino SE would be of any more help than EE. The OP should start here: http://www.forrestmims.com

Comment: I agree. I also have self help links for all users http://ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/socratic/model/index.html in my profile